# when i add a splash screen on my android app the app crashes

Tags: java, android, android-studio, splash-screen

i have created the app in android studio with java language and put a splash screen but when i run my app in android device the app crashed before adding the splash screen my app was running perfectly and i am running my app on my android device the android version on my device is android 10
here is the code of splash screen.

```
package com.example.androiddevelopment;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    Thread thread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                sleep(4000);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }; thread.start();
}
}
```

**here is the xml code of splash screen**
i am doing all this in constraint layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/maroon"
tools:context=".SplashActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="  Android Studio Development  "
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:background="@drawable/textview_border"
    android:textColor="@color/peach"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foregroundGravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.497"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/as" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="A project of IT-Souls"
    android:textColor="@color/peach"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.867"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />
```

Here is the android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/Theme.AndroidDevelopment">
<activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Chapter2" />
<activity android:name=".Chapter1" />
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">

</activity>
```

here is the logcat errors :

```
 2021-03-24 03:19:01.937 1338-1502/? E/WifiVendorHal: getWifiLinkLayerStats(l.939) failed {.code = ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED, .description = } 2021-03-24 03:19:02.076 537-537/? E/WifiHW: get chiptype error 2021-03-24 03:19:02.518 27621-27640/? E/HiApp.HUKSUtil: pool-5-thread-1{2116} <<< ERROR >>> getCertificateChain InvocationTargetException 2021-03-24 03:19:02.519 27621-27640/? E/HiApp.HUKSUtil: pool-5-thread-1{2116} <<< ERROR >>> X509Certificate is null! 2021-03-24 03:23:11.533 1338-3989/? E/HwProtectAreaService: nativeReadProtectAreaJava:error ret is -1 ! 2021-03-24 03:23:11.646 1338-5981/? E/HwProtectAreaService: nativeReadProtectAreaJava:error ret is -1 ! 2021-03-24 03:26:11.569 1338-1364/? E/libprocessgroup: Error encountered killing process cgroup uid 99025 pid 26108: No such file or directory 2021-03-24 03:26:11.630 26995-26995/? E/b$15: ║ onServiceDisconnected error : 2021-03-24 03:26:12.071 27970-27970/? E/RePlugin.PluginInfoList: load: Read Json error!
```

Comment: can you share the style of your activity? whatever do you want to hide the toolbar?

Comment: please share the complete error from the logcat

Comment: 2021-03-24 03:25:45.370 417-417/? I/HisiKeyMaster: hisi_km_get_key_characteristics success
2021-03-24 03:25:45.372 417-417/? I/HisiKeyMaster: hisi_km_begin start
2021-03-24 03:25:45.372 417-417/? I/HisiKeyMaster: Disable the enhanced crypto!
2021-03-24 03:25:45.372 417-417/? E/teec_app_load: realpath open file erro(No such file or directory), path=/vendor/bin/07070707-0707-0707-0707-070707070707.sec
2021-03-24 03:25:45.380 417-417/? I/HisiKeyMaster: out_params_buffer_len = 32

Comment: getSupportActionBar().hide(); remove it and run your app.

Comment: You just told that your app crashes as soon as it starts, To solve the issue you also need to provide the error message. Edit your question and add the error message too.

Comment: i have shared the complete error of logcat

Comment: Use this Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent); without thread to check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Logcat` so that you can see in what class, line of code, and what the error is and then debug it. Sorry, I can't comment because I have less then 50 reputation. The `Logcat` is located in the lower left of the program